# Play2War - MyModel is NOT an Entity Bean registered with this server

Tags: playframework, websphere, playframework-2.1, ebean

I'm building a Play 2.1.1 app to run on Websphere 8.5 and using [Play2War](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin) to build the war. The app runs fine when I use `play ~run` but when I build and deploy the war to Websphere, I get the error message:

`models.MyModel is NOT an Entity Bean registered with this server`

I tried creating the file `APP_HOME/conf/ebean.properties` and added the line:

```
ebean.search.jars=myplayapp.jar
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work.

Anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: I got the same problem when I run it using Tomcat7

Comment: did you set the @Entity annotation for MyModel?